# User HTML Helper to populate a DropDown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list with a list returned by a query to my object's facade. I've seen a couple examples here but nothing close enough to my use case. Seems like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("User.Affiliate", UserFacade.Instance.SelectAffiliates())%>
```

should work but doesn't.

Comment: What type does SelectAffiliates() return? Is it SelectList?

Comment: Nope...it's an IList. So I'd need to learn how to convert an IList to a SelectList, yes?

Comment: Yeah a select list is the prefered approach within mvc pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("User.Affiliate", 
    new SelectList(UserFacade.Instance.SelectAffiliates()))%>
```