# How to Populate a DropDown List using Razor and MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate & bind a drop down list control in MVC using Dapper, and I am having trouble finding a good example online. I can find plenty of examples of how to bind a statically defined drop down to a update a database (Like "Male" or "Female") and can get that to work. I can also find many examples of populating a drop down from a database, but I cannot get them to work in conjunction.

I just want my ProjectManifest/Create form to have a drop down populated with my current Projects.

I wish I was better at asking this question, but I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have tried dozens of variations in my code and different tutorials and questions on StackOverflow. The errors I receive from Visual Studio are so unhelpful, they are usually just NullReference exceptions, and there are so many variables in the HTML Helper function call I do not even know what is null.

These are some of the articles I have tried to use to help understand my problem:

- [Populate a Dropdown List in MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092995/populate-a-dropdown-list-in-mvc-view)
- [User HTML Helper to populate a DropDown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676840/user-html-helper-to-populate-a-dropdown-list)
- [Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680342/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-entityset)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9CJmLbnFko
- http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-bind-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx
- [Binding Data To DropDownList MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226780/binding-data-to-dropdownlist-mvc-razor)
- [Asp.Net MVC with Drop Down List, and SelectListItem Assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833652/asp-net-mvc-with-drop-down-list-and-selectlistitem-assistance)

I think the problem is in my index file, I do not understand Lambda expressions or what the expectation is to be in the arguments for the Html helper "DropDownListFor" or "DropDownList"

Index view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ProjectManifests", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManifestID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManifestID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManifestID)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, Model.Projects)
    ....

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Controller

```
public class ProjectManifestsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.ProjectManifestModel model = new Models.ProjectManifestModel();
        DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MTConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        ProjectRepository pr = new ProjectRepository();
        List<SelectListItem> projects = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Project p in pr.GetProjects())
        {
            projects.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = p.ProjectID.ToString(), Text = p.ProjectName });
        }
        model.Projects = projects;
        ViewBag.Projects = projects;
        return View();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ProjectManifestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ManifestID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    ....
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Projects { get; set; }

}
```

The state of this code produces a different error, my apologies:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Poscarp.TabLibrary.Project>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 29: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, Model.Projects)

Comment: NullReferenceExceptions can be very helpful... with the code posted above what is the actual error? what is null?

Comment: The code you have shown will NOT generate the error you have shown - it will generate _The ViewData item that has the key 'ProjectID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'_ because you did not pass a model to the view  (using `return View(model);`)

Comment: The error you have shown could only be generated if property `Projects` was `IEnumerable<Project>` (not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ProjectManifestModel` is the model in index.cshtml, try the following:

```
return View(model);
```

It looks like he's taking another class as a model.

Answer (score 0):

In the Index method of **ProjectManifestsController**, have you tried saving **SelectListItems** to **SelectList** and passing the **SelectList** to the view in **ViewBag**?  Like this:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(projects, "Value", "Text");
ViewBag.SelectList = selectList;
```

**Update**, if you have specific **ProjectID** you need to have selected in the **DropDownList**, then pass it as the fourth parameter to the **SelectList**

```
var selectList = new SelectList(projects, "Value", "Text", "ProjectID");
ViewBag.SelectList = selectList;
```

Alternatively you can set one of **SelectListItems** to [Selected](http://Update,%20if%20you%20have%20some%20specific%20ProjectID%20you%20need%20to%20have%20selected%20in%20the%20DropDownList,%20then%20pass%20it%20as%20the%20fourth%20parameter%20to%20the%20SelectList%20%20%20%20%09var%20selectList%20=%20new%20SelectList(projects,%20%22Value%22,%20%22Text%22,%20%22ProjectID%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ViewBag.SelectList%20=%20selectList;%20Alternatively,%20you%20can%20set%20one%20of%20SelectListItems%20to%20Selected%20when%20you%20create%20those%20in%20the%20foreach%20loop.)  in the **foreach** loop.

**Index** method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Models.ProjectManifestModel model = new Models.ProjectManifestModel();
        DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MTConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        ProjectRepository pr = new ProjectRepository();
        List<SelectListItem> projects = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Project p in pr.GetProjects())
        {
            projects.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = p.ProjectID.ToString(), Text = p.ProjectName });
        }
        model.Projects = projects;
        ViewBag.Projects = projects;
        //new code below
        var selectList = new SelectList(projects, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.SelectList = selectList;
        return View();
    }
```

In the Index view, you can use **@Html.DropDownList** helper with the **SelectList** from the **ViewBag** after casting it:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ProjectID", (SelectList)@ViewBag.SelectList)
```

Same as above, but this time there’s also option label (“-select-“) and HTML attributes used

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectID", (SelectList)@ViewBag.SelectList, "-select-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I hope this helps